# is there a name in math given to the ratio of two probabilities?

Tags: probability-theory

if an event has probability $\pi$ and the other event has probability $1-\pi$. is there a mathematical name or label for the ratio of those probabilities, $\frac{\pi}{1-\pi}$?

Comment: How can an event have probability $\pi> 1$ ?

Comment: I might be mistaken but I think it's called the odd.

Comment: Yes, this is called [odds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds); it is often used in gambling.

Comment: @AdamRubinson $\pi$ here is a variable representing a quantity in $[0,1]$, not $\pi \approx 3.14159\ldots$.

Answer (score 7):

If $\pi$ is the probability of some event $E$, then the ratio $\frac{\pi}{1-\pi}$ is called the [odds.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds)

The higher the odds the more likely $E$ is to occur. You usually express odds in terms of a ratio of the denominator.

Examples:

$\pi = 1/2$ gives even odds or $1:1$ odds.

$\pi = 2/3$ gives $2:1$ odds.

$\pi = 1/3$ gives $2:1$ odds *against*